# How to write Unit tests in jasmine angular for scroll function

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a scroll function to div. i need to mock the $Event passed to it. can some on help me writing the unit test for the below function Thanks.

```
<div (scroll)="scroll($event)">
</div>


  fetch = false;
  scroll($event){
  if($event.srcElement.scrollTop > 200) {
      this.fetch = true;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
it('should set fetch to true if scrollTop is greater than 200', () => {
  const mockEvent = { srcElement: { scrollTop: 201 } } as any;
  component.scroll(mockEvent);
  expect(component.fetch).toBeTrue();
});
```